# WPF и иконки Font Awesome

Tags: c#, wpf, шрифты, icon

Есть такой, весьма распространённый в web`е иконочный шрифт Font Awesome. По сути файл шрифтов + юникодовский символ дают на веб странице красивую иконку.

И вот я пытаюсь использовать такой же принцип в wpf приложении. По логике должно бы работать: c# вполне нормально дружит с юникодом, а начертание шрифта у него в файле. Но не работает.

Вот например стиль .fa-user-plus представляет собой символ f234
Делаю так:

```
FPInput.FontFamily = new FontFamily("file:///с:/fonts/#FontAwesome");
FPInput.Content =  "\uf234";
```

Собственно на форме вижу лишь пустой квадратик, то есть чего-то ему не хватает. Может кто понимает в чём тут проблема?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374349/add-icon-font-in-wpf

Comment: Вах, то что нужно, спасибо большое.